# Detect input changes on form choicefield

Tags: jquery, python, django, forms, choicefield

I have a form in a view. When the user make a change on this form, I show a "save changes" button with Jquery.

Here is the jquery code :

```
$('input').change(function() { 
            //Show the "save changes" button
        });
```

It works great with different input (text, integer, checkbox,...) but not with the choicefield.
When I change the value in the choicefield, there is no input change catched, but if I submit the form, the new value of the choicefield is indeed submited.

How can I catch the change of value on the choicefield ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "choicefield" is not an input. It is a select.

Comment: Thank you ! Can I ask you where you can find this info ? I didn't find it on the django doc for forms.

Comment: This is nothing to do with Django, but simple HTML.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('select').change(function() { 
        //Show the "save changes" button
    });
```